# In Haskell, what does the map function mean when you only pass it a list?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, parameters, pointfree, partial-application

In a Haskell project I'm given to debug, there are instances in the code where `map` is used with only one parameter - a list - is passed.

For example

```
printReports :: [Report] -> IO ()
printReports = putStrLn . unlines . map show
```

and

```
printRuns' :: [Run] -> IO ()
printRuns' = putStrLn . unlines . map showRecipes'
```

What does `map` mean/do in this context?

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application

Comment: Also the applied argument is a function, not a list. `map` is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` which is the same as `(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])`.

Comment: You can read `f . g . h` as a "pipe", which takes data and passes it through `h`, then `g`, then `f`.  `map show` is one of the functions in the pipe (it takes a list and converts every element of the list to a stream)

Answer (score 10):

Type of map:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So you have to provide a function from `a` to `b` and a list of type `a`.

In your examples, the function is already given (`show` and `showRecipes'`), and therefore, you only have to provide for `printReports` and `printRuns'` a list.

What happened there is called ***partially applied function***, see here 
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application

Answer (score 10):

As others have said, `map show` is a partially applied function, and reading up on that is a good idea. But the code you've given is also an example of the [point-free](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style of programming, and it may be easier for you to understand it as such. The function `printReports` could also have been written as

```
printReports xs = (putStrLn . unlines . map show) xs
```

or, equivalently,

```
printReports xs = putStrLn . unlines . map show $ xs
```

Generally speaking, all of the following are equivalent:

```
myFunction x y z = someExpression x y z
myFunction x y = someExpression x y
myFunction x = someExpression x
myFunction = someExpression
```

That's a slight oversimplification, but it will get you started.

Comment: They're equivalent in that they all give the same result. They may differ in performance in some situations, and the Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction may cause problems if there's no type signature. But they're equivalent in the most important ways.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, if you have something like this...

```
foo = bar . foobar . blafasel
```

... you can mentally substitute the dots by `$` and add a variable on both sides

```
foo x = bar $ foobar $ blafasel x
```

Why this works is already explained in the other answers, but this trick helps me to read point-free style without much thinking.

Answer (score 2):

In this context map apply the show function to each Report present in the list. 
The result should look like [show report0, show report1,... ,show reportn]

Say differently you pass a list of report and the function map, **map** for each item of type of report in the list the show function.

The way yours function are built correspond to the [point free style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-free_programming).